# finding source code dosen't work in python

Tags: python

I'm working in python and I'm trying to get the source code of a tik tok video ( don't judge me) and something doesn't work properly. all I'm getting is a JSON. Actually probably it works but I don't understand how and why so I need help. this is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = str('https://www.tiktok.com/@_lu.bov.che_/video/6692083446153481477')
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

and this is the output

```
    {"statusCode":200,"contentType":"application/json","content":""}
```

I want to get the source code of the webpage. Please help me

Comment: What do you mean, the source code of a video? A video does not have source code.

Comment: Setting a different User Agent here changes the response to HTML, see the duplicate.